# border-radius on <th>. No border rounding

Tags: css

I have css looks like that:

```
#caltable th {
    border: solid 1px #333;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background: #f00;
}
```

But this is what i've got in browser (Chrome/FF):

[image]

The question is how to get black line also rounded?

Comment: After adding `-moz-border-radius: 7px;` I tried it in FF 3.6 and the black border was curved.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change `border-collapse:collapse` to `border-collapse:separate` on the `<table>`.

You should also add support for browsers which are not at the newwest version:

```
-moz-border-radius: 7px;
-o-border-radius: 7px;
-ms-border-radius: 7px;
-webkit-border-radius: 7px;
```

Comment: Thx a lot! `border-collapse:separate` is what needed

Comment: What do we do when we want both `border-collapse: collapse` and a `border-radius`? Why do they have to be mutually exclusive?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to. It's done automatically

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/e9ab8

http://phpcode.eu/images/1317547931.png

Comment: You just lucky, because your code is incorrect. Check out  - http://jsfiddle.net/EDyGU/